# bash command fails in tomcat/java Runtime.getRuntime.exec(), but works from command line

Tags: java, linux, bash, shell, tomcat

I have a tomcat webapp that runs a process in the shell because several of the utilities are not available in java. **This code works perfectly on other machines**, but there is a mysterious problem on my public server.

```
String[] textAnalysisPipeline = {
    "/bin/sh",
    "-c",
    "/bin/cat " + inputfileLoc +
    " | tee /tmp/debug1 | " + loadJar + " " + jarOptLookupLoc + " " + optHfstLoc +
    " 2>/dev/null | " + "tail -n+5" + // get rid of the header that hfst-ol.jar produces
    " | tee /tmp/debug2 | cut -f 1-2" + // get rid of the "0.0" weights
    " | tee /tmp/debug3 | " + cgConvLoc +
    " | tee /tmp/debug4 | " + vislcg3Loc + " -g " + vislcg3DisGrammarLoc +  // disambiguate with the constraint grammar
    " | tee /tmp/debug5 > " + outputfileLoc};
log.debug("Text analysis pipeline: "+textAnalysisPipeline[2]);
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(textAnalysisPipeline);
process.waitFor();
```

I print the string to the log, and it looks like this: (`path/to/` is not the actual paths)

```
/bin/cat /path/to/inputFile | tee /tmp/debug1 | java -jar /path/to/hfst-ol.jar /path/to/analyser.ohfst 2>/dev/null | tail -n+5 | tee /tmp/debug2 | cut -f 1-2 | tee /tmp/debug3 | /usr/local/bin/cg-conv | tee /tmp/debug4 | /path/to/vislcg3 -g /path/to/grammar.rlx | tee /tmp/debug5 > /path/to/outputFile
```

If I copy this pipeline from the log and run it from the bash command line, I get the desired output all the way to the end of the pipeline. However, when the tomcat server runs the command, it produces an empty file. The debug files `debug1` and `debug2` are as expected, but `debug3` and thereafter is empty, which suggests that the pipeline fails at `cut -f 1-2` (see UPDATE 1 below).

OS - Fedora 22
java - openjdk 1.8.0_77
tomcat - 7.0.39
sh --> bash - 4.3.42(1)-release

================================================================
UPDATE 1:

This does not seem to be a problem with `cut`. I wrote a short python script, `cut.py` to achieve the same functionality as `cut -f 1-2` (remove `'\t0.0'` from the end of each line)

```
import re, sys
myRE = re.compile( r'\s+0\.0$' )
for line in sys.stdin :
    sys.stdout.write( myRE.sub( '', line ) )
```

Using `cut.py` in place of `cut`, I get the same problem. With the server `debug3` and beyond is empty, but if I copy-paste from the log to the interactive shell, everything works fine.

================================================================
UPDATE 2:

I also wrote a simple bash script to run the pipeline so that tomcat/java only runs the bash script with one argument for the input/output filename. If I run the script from an interactive shell, it works, but the results are no different in tomcat, using `cut` or `cut.py` in the shell script.

Comment: I would suggest actually echoing the command-line built from string concatenation. Verify that the exact command printed works in terminal. Many a times we miss out some quotes while generating the command line via string concat. asking this, because there is no logical reason `cut` should fail in script & pass via command line.

Comment: @anishsane This is actually what I did. It prints the string to the log, `log.debug("Text analysis pipeline: "+textAnalysisPipeline[2]);` and then I copy-paste it to the command line.

Comment: Have you tried running the command `/bin/sh -c "/bin/cat ..."` directly from your bash command line (rather than just `/bin/cat ...`)?

Comment: @Smeeheey I hadn't tried that, but I just did and it gives good output.

Comment: For debugging, using `"/bin/sh", "-xc", ...` might produce useful cues.

Comment: The relative paths mean you are forced to run the pipeline in a specific directory.  This is hardly the reason for the failure (given that `cut` seems to be problematic) but perhaps something you would want to fix; and maybe this should be pointed out in the question.

Comment: We agree that all the paths are absolute?  Have you checked what process.getErrorStream() returns? And the exit value return by waitFor?

Comment: @tripleee The paths are actually absolute. I edited the question.

Comment: @NicolasFilotto How do I collect stderr from `process`? I tried `InputStream error = process.getErrorStream();`, but got an error. I also do not know how to get the exit value from waitFor. :(

Comment: waitFor returns an integer which is the exit value of your process

Comment: You still have not provided `sh -xc` output for us to look at.

Comment: Sorry I have been sick all week. Looks like I have 17 hours to try to get something useful out of this bounty. ;) @tripleee I don't know how to view the stderr from `sh -xc`. I did add `2>/tmp/...` at each step, and found that `cg-conv` and `vislcg3` both give an error `/usr/local/bin/vislcg3: error while loading shared libraries: libcg3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This seems to indicate a problem with `PATH` in tomcat's environment. It is in `/usr/local/lib/libcg3.so.0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default installation on most systems, Tomcat does not have the same environment as your user. It does not run, for instance, your .bashrc .profile or whatever you have in your login script, so all variables set in your user shell environment are different.

You can check that by comparing the `env` command with both users: yours and by having it called by your java program, something like:

```
String[] textAnalysisPipeline = {"/bin/sh","-c","/usr/bin/env > /tmp/env.txt"}; //or wherever the 'env' command is in your system
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(textAnalysisPipeline);
...
```

And compare the content of the `/tmp/env.txt` with the `env` execution with your user... they are probably very different.

Look for the following variables:

- PATH
- CLASSPATH
- JAVA_HOME

I have already the same problem in the past. I suggest the following approach:

1. Use absolute path for *everything*, including the calls for "java", "tee", "tail" and libs (jar files)... you have in your command;
2. Change the environment configuration under which your Tomcat runs to reach all the applications you call in your command (usually by calling a script that configures all the necessary `PATH` variable (do not forget the `JAVA_HOME` and `CLASSPATH` to your jar files!). Check the Startup.sh and Catalina.sh for a suitable place to include your stuff;
3. Change your command to redirect the error output not to `/dev/null` as it is in your message, but to some log file somewhere in your system that your application can write (usually `/tmp/exec.log` is just fine) so you can be sure of the shell execution problem. I bet it will be something like: `sh: ****: command not found` or `Error: Unable to access jarfile` or some message of your application not being able to locate an object, so you will be sure of what application you call in your script is not in the `PATH` environment variable or what libs you don't have in it... usually both

For additional info on this, check https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath

Hope this helps...

Comment: point 3 was helpful: `cg-conv` and `vislcg3` both give an error `error while loading shared libraries: libcg3.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. This seems to indicate a problem with `PATH` in tomcat's environment. It is in `/usr/local/lib/libcg3.so.0`.

Comment: Calling `env` from tomcat gave the following `PATH`: `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`. I can't find how to change this in `startup.sh` or `catalina.sh`. Is it taken from the user who runs tomcat?

Comment: The combination of comparing the output of `env` and adding `2>/tmp/...` to every step helped me to find the problem. As I wrote in my first comment to this answer, there was a problem with accessing shared libraries. I found in my own user's environment `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib`, but there was nothing like that in tomcat's `env`. I wrote a short shell script to have the tomcat user declare that variable before starting the server, and now it works perfectly! :-)

Answer (score 3):

This is mainly an aside or perhaps a workaround, but your pipeline can be simplified significantly.  The `cat` is [useless](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html) and the `tail` and `cut` can be replaced with a single Awk script.

```
tee /tmp/debug1 <path/to/inputFile |
java -jar path/to/hfst-ol.jar path/to/analyser.ohfst 2>/dev/null |
tee /tmp/debug2 |
awk -F '\t' 'NR>5 { print $1 FS $2 }' |
tee /tmp/debug3 |
/usr/local/bin/cg-conv |
tee /tmp/debug4 |
path/to/vislcg3 -g path/to/grammar.rlx |
tee /tmp/debug5 > path/to/outputFile
```

Comment: Good points. This is not the first time that someone has convinced me that `awk` is worth learning. Maybe I'll do that someday.... ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ProcessBuilder`. Use the single-string form of `Runtime.exec` is not a good style. Better option is to use `ProcessBuilder`, and split up the arguments yourself rather than relying on Java to split them for you which it does very naively.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", /*...*/);
pb.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process p = pb.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a pattern in scripts and (sometimes especially) crontabs where the `$PATH` variable that you are using for your script differs from what you are using for your interactive shell. This results in commands failing mysteriously in one environment but working elsewhere.

I would strongly recommend embedding the full path of all of the tools that you are using into the invocation that you are building. It's possible that `cut` is in a directory that is not picked up when you run that process. Putting in the full path like `/usr/bin/cut` will make certain two things: that no one sneaks in an unexpected version of `cut` into your path, and also that it won't matter if the environment you are in doesn't have `/usr/bin` in `$PATH`.

Comment: It seems unlikely that `/usr/bin` would be missing from the `PATH` even in a severely constrained environment; but this is certainly another thing for the OP to investigate and hopefully clarify in the question.

Comment: It looks like it may be a problem with `PATH`, but not with `cut`. See my comment on @FJunqueira 's answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy the command from the log and run it from the command line, do you execute it as the same user than the user running Tomcat?

The Tomcat user might not have enough permissions to read one of the files in your command.

On my Ubuntu system, the default Tomcat 7 user is called tomcat7. Running a command as another user can be done using the [sudo](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) command :

```
sudo -u tomcat7 /bin/sh -c 'myCommand'
```

Source : [How do you process an entire command as sudo that involves redirecting or piping?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/106663/how-do-you-process-an-entire-command-as-sudo-that-involves-redirecting-or-piping).